# echo a list of values by foreach loop in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

In PHP I want to echo some values in the array by foreach loop, but I don't know how to do this.
I tried many ways such as **$key => $value** and **print_r** or **echo** codes but They didn't work.
for example in this array I want to echo all ***score*** values one by one:

```
$students = array(
"Beginner" => [
    "levelA" => [
        [
            "firstname" => "Pouya",
            "lastname" => "Parsaei",
            "phonenumber" => 9339658613,
            "score" => 100
        ],
        [
            "firstname" => "Ali",
            "lastname" => "Soli",
            "phonenumber" => 9179892233,
            "score" => 80
        ],
    ],
    "levelB" => [
        [
            "firstname" => "peyman",
            "lastname" => "tabibi",
            "phonenumber" => 933964353,
            "score" => 50
        ],
        [
            "firstname" => "pari",
            "lastname" => "ehsani",
            "phonenumber" => 9175389988,
            "score" => 75
        ],
    ],
],
"Intermediate" => [
    "levelD" => [
        [
            "firstname" => "Pouya",
            "lastname" => "Parsaei",
            "phonenumber" => 9339658613,
            "score" => 100
        ],
        [
            "firstname" => "Ali",
            "lastname" => "Soli",
            "phonenumber" => 9179892233,
            "score" => 80
        ],
    ],
    "levelE" => [

        [
            "firstname" => "Pouya",
            "lastname" => "Parsaei",
            "phonenumber" => 9339658613,
            "score" => 100
        ],
        [
            "firstname" => "Ali",
            "lastname" => "Soli",
            "phonenumber" => 9179892233,
            "score" => 80
        ],
    ],
],
);
```

I tried with these codes but I couldn't do it:

```
// foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
//      if ($value < 75)continue;
//      print_r($key);echo "<br>";
//      print_r($value); echo "<br>";
// echo "$key : {$value["levelA"][0]["firstname"]}
// {$value["levelA"][0]["lastname"]} <br>";
// }
```

***I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next time, just [RTFM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-52) and use [var_dunp.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for debugging.

```
foreach($students as $outerKey => $outerValue)
{
    foreach($outerValue as $key => $value)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i<count($value); $i++)
        {
            echo $value[$i]['score'].'<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
100
80
50
75
100
80
100
80
```

Comment: Great. thank you. that worked. I got my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If only the scores are what you want you could simply use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) as below.

```php
array_walk_recursive($students, function($val, $key) {
    if ($key === 'score') {
        echo "score: $val" . PHP_EOL;
    }
});
```

Result:

```php
score: 100
score: 80
score: 50
score: 75
score: 100
score: 80
score: 100
score: 80
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I wanted to do it by **foreach** loop, I got the answer in other's answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$students = array(
    "Beginner" => [
        "levelA" => [
            [
                "firstname" => "Pouya",
                "lastname" => "Parsaei",
                "phonenumber" => 9339658613,
                "score" => 100
            ],
            [
                "firstname" => "Ali",
                "lastname" => "Soli",
                "phonenumber" => 9179892233,
                "score" => 80
            ],
        ],
        "levelB" => [
            [
                "firstname" => "peyman",
                "lastname" => "tabibi",
                "phonenumber" => 933964353,
                "score" => 50
            ],
            [
                "firstname" => "pari",
                "lastname" => "ehsani",
                "phonenumber" => 9175389988,
                "score" => 75
            ],
        ],
    ],
    "Intermediate" => [
        "levelD" => [
            [
                "firstname" => "Pouya",
                "lastname" => "Parsaei",
                "phonenumber" => 9339658613,
                "score" => 100
            ],
            [
                "firstname" => "Ali",
                "lastname" => "Soli",
                "phonenumber" => 9179892233,
                "score" => 80
            ],
        ],
        "levelE" => [

            [
                "firstname" => "Pouya",
                "lastname" => "Parsaei",
                "phonenumber" => 9339658613,
                "score" => 100
            ],
            [
                "firstname" => "Ali",
                "lastname" => "Soli",
                "phonenumber" => 9179892233,
                "score" => 80
            ],
        ],
    ],
);

foreach ($students as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ': <br> <br>';
    foreach ($value as $key => $value_1) {
        echo $key . ': <br><br>';
        foreach ($value_1 as $key => $value_2) {
            $key++;
            echo 'Serial Number: ' . $key . '<br> First Name: ' . $value_2['firstname'] . '<br> Last Name: ' . $value_2['lastname'] .
                '<br> Phone Number: ' . $value_2['phonenumber'] . '<br> Score: ' . $value_2['score'] . '<br><br>';
        }
    }
}
```

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc62W.png)

Comment: Thank you my friend for that it really worked.

Comment: Welcome friend!